# Can I bit shift 0 to the beginning?

Tags: java, bit, bit-shift, bitmask

I'm trying to learn bit shifting/masking. Here is my code:

```
    int health = 511; // max 512, 9 bits
    int aimAngle = 510; // max 512, 9 bits
    int test = 511; // max 512, 9 bits
    boolean bool = false; // max 1, 1 bit
    int packed;
    packed = health | aimAngle << 9 | test << 18 | (bool?1:0) << 19;
    Debug.log("health: " + ((packed ) & 0b111111111));
    Debug.log("aimAngle: " + ((packed >> 9) & 0b111111111));
    Debug.log("test: " + ((packed >> 18) & 0b111111111));
    Debug.log("bool: " + ((packed >> 19) & 0b1));
```

I'm getting all the values correctly except bool. It's always 1. What is wrong? Can't I shift zero to the beginning?

Comment: @Tom sure, no problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test` is up to nine bits long. You shift it right 18 places. Therefore it occupies bits 18 to 27. You need to shift `bool` to place 28 to avoid it, not to place 19.

The 19th digit of `packed` is the second digit of `test`, which is a 1.